# On double exponents: how to evaluate/simplify $2^{a^b c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponentiation

While solving an Algebra exercise I came across this expression $2^{a^b c}$ and simplified it in the following manner:

$$
2^{a^b c} = 2^{(a^b)c} = (2^{a^b})^c = (2^a)^b)^c = (2^{ab})^c = 2^{abc}.
$$

I have obviously done something wrong here. Not only because

$$2^{a^b c} = 2^{abc} \iff a^b c = abc,$$

but also because

$$2^{x^0 y} \overset{?}= 2^{x0y} =  1 \text{ and } 2^{x^0 y} = 2^y.$$

I can't for the life of me find out what I did wrong. All the steps I took seem justified. Can someone please point out where my mistake is?

Comment: $2^{a^b}\ne (2^a)^b$. Note that $(2^a)^b=2^{ab}$

Comment: @5201314 Such a silly mistake. I wrote down some examples using very small numbers and it worked, so I didn't question it. Thanks for the response. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: $2^{(a^b)}\neq (2^a)^b$, In such cases  we can use brackets to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

$2^{a^bc}$ is $2^{a^bc}$, and that's all there is to it. Your assertion that $2^{a^b}=(2^a)^b$ is as false as a standalone statement as it is inside this more convoluted expression.